# Cannot access `https://i.stack.imgur.com`: ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

Tags: support, imgur

When I click image links that use `https://i.stack.imgur.com` on the questions, I am getting an `ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED` error. I tried it from home and work and nothing changed.

Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpWZJ.png.

Can it be a regional problem? I am connecting from Turkey. How can I solve it?

Comment: That image works for me. Try a VPN that connects from outside Turkey.

Comment: There was a problem a while back with the Imgur service, but it has been fixed now for over a week. I'm not having any connection problems on my end, nor have I heard any reports from other users.  Are you behind a proxy server or an ISP that might be blocking it?

Comment: It works for me and I seem to remember Turkey blocking imgur on several occasions. Maybe you can get to it via hide.me unless that's blocked as well.

Comment: I tried  with/without vpn and nothing changed

Comment: So they're using IIS/7.5, Hope they already fixed the iis vulnerabilities..:)

Comment: With Vodafone operator (Turkey) shows pictures. I guess they didn't notice the ban. Interesting.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

imgur has been blocked in Turkey for 2 years. Just try using VPN.

Comment: Seems like this is indeed the case, lots of posts from 2017 in /r/turkey seem to confirm this https://www.google.ca/search?q=imgur+blocked+in+turkey&oq=imgur+blocked+in+turkey&aqs=chrome..69i57.2212j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: And I thought Great Firewall of China was bad!

Comment: Ohh god! It's open now for Turkey. Everything will be great :)

Answer (score 12):

I can't verify if this still works, but according to [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Turkey/comments/4emzdz/on_vacation_in_turkey_imgur_doesnt_work_on_my/) ([thanks @meagar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358373/cannot-access-https-i-stack-imgur-com-err-connection-closed#comment525498_358374)) you should be able to get around the block by using different DNS servers.

Try [Google Public DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using):

> The Google Public DNS IP addresses (IPv4) are as follows:
>
> - 8.8.8.8
> - 8.8.4.4
>
> The Google Public DNS IPv6 addresses are as follows:
>
> - 2001:4860:4860::8888
> - 2001:4860:4860::8844

Comment: I tried but it didn't work me, thanks anyway.

Comment: ps, this works for blocked websites (like thepiratebay.org ) in norway

Answer (score 11):

**Better late than never!**

@New: You can also add "p" letter at the end of the imgur url, e.g. *i.imgurp.com/....*

I come up with a solution via using DuckDuckGo and [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/switcheroo-redirector/cnmciclhnghalnpfhhleggldniplelbg)(Switcheroo Redirector) called as `Switcheroo Redirector`

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ > https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https://i.stack.imgur.com/

https://i.imgur.com/ > https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https://i.imgur.com/
```

Conspicuously to use VPN is the best way (as surfing on the Internet) to go yet cuz of US dollar's high rate it nowadays seems not a plausible way. In lieu just follow the no-frills method. I think at least one of the images below is seeable.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5):

I created a script which converts any imgur links into web.archive.org link which allows you to see the images. Save the script below into your browser's bookmark and click the bookmark.

```
javascript:(function()%7B%24("img").each(function(ignore%2C e) %7Bvar %24e %3D %24(e)%3Bif (%24e.attr("src").startsWith("https%3A%2F%2Fi.stack.imgur")) %7B%24e.attr("src"%2C "http%3A%2F%2Fweb.archive.org%2Fweb%2F" %2B %24e.attr("src"))%3B%7D%7D)%7D)()
```

Comment: Would you provide more info about how to save the script into browser's bookmark?

Comment: Sure. On chrome, show the bookmarks bar by using `ctrl + shift + b` shortcut. On the bookmark tab, right click and choose the 'add page' option. Two input fields will pop up. Name field is up to you. Paste the code into the 'URL' input field and save it.

Comment: Thank you. And is there other wetsite other than web.archive.org that can be used to redirect  any imgur links? For web.archive.org can not be accessed either for me.

Comment: @YavuzKoca. Thx, it worked for me. Edit your solution: After saving the script to the browser's bookmark, drag and drop it to the Bookmark area on top of the browser to permanently locate it there. Then, whenever you see imgur-imaged SOF page, just click the bookmark that is put into the Bookmark area. All the imgur images are shown in the related page.

Comment: @ErdoganCEVHER exactly

Comment: web.archive runs slowly in a minute manner, but it pays off to test

Answer (score 2):

With respect to @snr 's answer, if you're using `firefox` you can add [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/tr/firefox/addon/redirector/) add-on to your browser and then add a new `redirect` configuration as follows;

```
Example Url: https://i.stack.imgur.com/whatever
Include Pattern: https://i.stack.imgur.com/*
Redirect to: https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https://i.stack.imgur.com/$1
```

Afterwards, you should check the `wildcard` as `Pattern type`. Finally, you should be able to see your `Example result` as;

```
https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https://i.stack.imgur.com/whatever
```

Click save and now when you click an `imgur` link, you will have no problem.

Additionally, if you click `Show advanced options` below and check every box in `Apply to`, this add-on will change the links and you will be able to see the images. Yay!

Comment: This works! However, the pattern is `*i.stack.imgur.com/*` and the redirect is `https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=$1i.stack.imgur.com/$2`. For some reason if I don't match pattern for the protocol prefix, it won't work.