# Do we need a tag [geoblocking] on Meta, given that SO and the SO Developer Survey/Qualtrics do it?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, geoblocking

Geoblocking, in particular of SO or SO-related content or sites, is an issue which comes up on Meta and damages user experience. Does it deserve a tag on Meta?

Examples:

- [The 2020 Developer Survey Link is blocked in my country](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393664/the-2020-developer-survey-link-is-blocked-in-my-country/)
- [Why can't I open the 2019 Developer Survey link?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379318/why-cant-i-open-the-2019-developer-survey-link)

  - *"If you use security or ad-blocking plugins, you may see error messages"*
  - Qualtrics geoblocks Cuba, Iran, North Korea, Syria, the Crimea region of Ukraine, also Turkey (2020) <sup>1</sup>, due to U.S. economic sanctions
- [Cannot access imgur images on SO from Turkey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358373/cannot-access-https-i-stack-imgur-com-err-connection-closed) since 2017.

  - also reportedly pastebin, Wikipedia

---

<sup>1</sup> As reported by https://www.comparitech.com/privacy-security-tools/blockedinturkey/

Comment: I'm interested to see questions like these categorised. I've added the tag, help contribute to the tag wiki https://meta.stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/1972

Comment: @SamuelLiew: Neat. The tag wiki had no definition, so I just added one.